# Need to link "Bring your own function" to static web app but can't get it to happen

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-static-web-app

I have a **serverless Azure Function api in JS** that I want to **link to my static web app**. When I try this in the portal ***I select the subscription > function app > click link.*** But nothing happens. No error, the button changes color for a second and then turns back to being clickable.

I then tried doing it via CLI - with a call like this.

```
 az staticwebapp functions link -n my-web-app -g my-resource-group --function-resource-id "/subscriptions/blahblahblahsub/resourceGroups/my-resource-group/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/my-functionapp"
```

However this just gives an error

```
`No module named 'azure.mgmt.web.v2020_12_01'`
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to link your Function API successfully with the Azure static web app make sure you create an Azure Static Web app resource with Standard plan and not Free plan as Bring your own Function is only supported in Standard plan of Azure static web app.

Select any Javascript sample repository from this [Github repo](https://github.com/staticwebdev/)

Created Azure static web app with standard plan by adding one github repository from above samples :-

[image]

***Selected APIs > Production > Link > And Linked my Function app which has JS Function trigger like below:-***

[image]

[image]

**With Azure CLI:-**

Copied Resource ID of Function app from below:-

[image]

My Function trigger deployed and running successfully inside the Function app like below:-

[image]

Below Azure CLI command [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/staticwebapp/backends?view=azure-cli-latest#az-staticwebapp-backends-link%28%29)

```bash
az staticwebapp backends link -n valleyswajsfuncapi -g v-siddheshrg12 --backend-resource-id "/subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourceGroups/siddheshrg12/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/siliconfunc650" --backend-region UKSouth
```

[image]

[image]

You can make use of this [vannilla-api](https://github.com/staticwebdev/vanilla-api) repository which will Deploy a static web app with Functions API.

Comment: Thank you!    I didn't need to change anything in my config and the portal still just silently failed for me .   What did work was the change from  az staticwebapp functions link  to  az staticwebapp backends link.